# Reversing a Singly Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse

I know there are multiple questions on the same problem on SO. But somewhere, I am not able to get the logic.

The function that reverses the Linked List is as follows:

```
void reverse()
{
    struct node *curr=head, *prev=NULL;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    head = prev;
}
```

I am using a global head pointer and the structure of a node in the linked list is:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
```

Here, every time the `curr` node will point to the `prev` node and at the end when the list is traversed by the `curr` node, `prev` node will point to the last node in the list which I make as the head pointer.

But, this logic doesn't reverse the list and only prints the first node. So, I think the code is executed only once but I am not able to catch the mistake.

The other functions to make the program complete:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;

void add(int n)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     temp->data = n;
     temp->next = NULL;
     if(head == NULL)
     {
        head = temp;
        return;
     }
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void print()
{
    struct node *temp = head;
     printf("\n The List is : ");
     while(temp!=NULL)
     {
        printf(" %d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void reverse()
{
    struct node *curr=head, *prev=NULL;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    head = prev;
}

int main(void)
{
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
    add(4);
    add(5);
    print();
    reverse();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strongly recommend finishing your `print()` function with `putchar('\n');` or some other way of ending the output line.  Your output may not appear timely otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you elaborate please?

Comment: Many programs run in line-buffered output mode, which means that an output doesn't appear until there's a newline at the end.  It may matter less on Windows, but on Unix, it is definitely an issue.  It's also usually tidier to have a function finish its output line.  Other functions can assume that their output is going to start at the beginning of a line.  Spaces before and after newlines are often suboptimal, too, but that's another issue.  Generally, make sure that you print newlines at the end of output, more than at the beginning.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler got it :). I am using Ubuntu by the way :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting the `curr->next` pointer which is then used to iterate the list. Code should be more like this:

```
void reverse()
{
    struct node *curr=head, *prev=NULL;
    struct node *next;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;
}
```